# Can I turn my normal website into a fully responsive website by using Bootstrap /

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a old website which is written in HTML, Javascript, Jquery. i want to convert it into fully responsive website by using Bootstrap 3. is it possible to do that with out changing major content in my old website ?

Comment: Well, it still takes integration. So you'll to put everything within the appropriate divs and just include the js and stylesheets. Shouldn't take too long, especially if you have just a small static html site

Answer (score 2):

If you are very, very good with CSS, you can do a lot of it without fiddling with the html, but not touching the html will not be possible. You can rename the classes that do similar layouts to the ones you currently use, but you'd have to be extra good at understanding CSS and the implications of doing it that way. You can take a look at the docs on GetBootstrap.com and see that. If you are good with find and replace, you can replace the head structure, you can do a find and replace on the the class names but if your columns are not contained in a certain way, such as .something (the wrapper) > .row (the clearing row for all the colums) and then the .col-*-* you'll need to structure it so it works.